# Spring REST mandatory @RequestParam for all the API

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Is there a way to configure @RequestParam for all the API in a class.
I want all my API to have a mantory request param like token.

Comment: Would not be better to use a header instead of a `@RequestParam`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the [`@RequestMapping#params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) annotation element?

`@RequestMapping` is an annotation that you can put on the top of your controller and then you can provide the required parameter names that need to be present for it to be accessible on your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(params = { "token" }, ...)
public class MyRequiredTokenEndpoints { ... }
```